# How to keep the chiplist autocomplete suggestions open after a chip is added or removed?

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete

In Angular I have made an autocomplete chiplist component. When the user chooses to remove or add an item, the suggestion list disappears and the input field is left empty.

Instead of this behaviour I'd like to keep the autocomplete list open (or re-open it again), sothat the user does not need to trigger it by typing in the input field.

So currently the autocomplete is opened the moment the user begins typing;

> chip-list.component.ts

```
constructor() {
  this.filteredItems = this.itemCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
    map((item: string | T) => {
      if (typeof item === 'string') {
        return this._filter(item);
      }
      return this.allItems.filter(
        (x) => this.selectedItems.indexOf(x) === -1
      );
    })
  );
}
```

> chip-list.component.html

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="group" class="mat-form-field-prefix">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Item selection">
    <mat-icon *ngIf="iconName" matPrefix>{{ iconName }}</mat-icon>
    <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let item of selectedItems"
      [selectable]="false"
      [removable]="true"
      (removed)="remove(item)"
      (click)="remove(item)"
    >
      {{ this.getItemName(item) }}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder=""
      #itemInput
      (click)="itemCtrl.valueChanges.emit()"
      [formControl]="itemCtrl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      class="mat-form-field-infix"
    />
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let item of filteredItems | async"
      [value]="item"
    >
      {{ this.getItemName(item) }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 4):

call function of `openPanel()`. `#operationTrigger` name this reference whatever you want.

```
<input
      matInput
      placeholder=""
      #itemInput
      #operationTrigger="matAutocompleteTrigger"
      (click)="itemCtrl.valueChanges.emit()"
      [formControl]="itemCtrl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
      class="mat-form-field-infix"
    />
```

and in your **mat-option** in **mat-autocomplete** call a function on click like this.

```
(click)="operationTrigger.openPanel()"

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let item of filteredItems | async"
      [value]="item"
      (click)="operationTrigger.openPanel()">
      {{ this.getItemName(item) }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

hope it will work out for you.

Comment: This does not work unfortunatelly. The autocomplete list is still open after an option was clicked.

Comment: Did you find any solution? @Klyner

Comment: For me it's working, but I do see the panel gets closed and reopened, this is terrible...